# Add an image to NSImageView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, user-interface

How do I add an image to NSImageView **with Interface Builder**? I do not want to do this programatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the info palette there is a textfield for entering an image file's name (extension optional):

[image]

Keep in mind that referenced images must have been added to your Xcode project. <sup>(thanks @sgermain06)</sup>

Comment: Make sure your image is in your project. That's the only requirement :)